# C# Asp.net mvc identity, users logging out very quickly

Tags: asp.net-mvc, identity

I am using Asp.net identity membership. This is my code :

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
    {
        AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
        LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),  
        ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(45),
        Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
        {
            // Enables the application to validate the security stamp when the user logs in.
            // This is a security feature which is used when you change a password or add an external login to your account.  
            OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, User>(
                validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0),
                regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))

        }
    });
```

As you can see ExpireTimeSpan set to 45 minutes, but after login,  users log out very quickly, about in ten minutes if he not makes any http request. When i check inspect element i saw the following :
After Login :
[image]

And after ten minutes :

[image]

As You can see AspNet.ApplicationCookie has been replaced by _RequestVerificationToken but session id still exists.